# People putting $\$\{\}\{\}\{\}\{\}\{\}\$$ at the end of their comments?

Tags: support, mathjax, comment

I have noticed some people putting something like $\$\{\}\{\}\{\}\$$ at the end of their comments (for example, André Nicolas' comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721381/how-to-solve-fracddx-int-pix2-sint-textdt-using-the-fundame#comment1507748_721381)). I can see the curly braces fast enough because MathJax doesn't load fast for me. Why are there curly braces at the end of the comment? What do they do?

Comment: They make the submitted text long enough for the character minimum ($15$ characters) $\hphantom{\text{some place holder text for length ;)}}$.

Comment: I do not know whether it was discussed on this meta, too, but on MO [some people complained about it](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/462/on-using-mathjax-to-create-white-space).

Comment: you can also use $\tiny\phantom{phantoms...huh...}\! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \! \!  $

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As remarked above in the comments (and in a now deleted answer), some users use `${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$` to overcome minimum length requirements in comments (and answers, too). This is rendered as... pretty much n${}$oth${}$ing, though Math${}{}{}{}{}$Jax does have to render its nothingness.

[Zero-width spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_Width_Space) (and related characters) can also fill this purpose, but they are not as commonly known in the math community (and are somewhat more difficult to input). there​are​zero​​width​spaces​here​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​width​spaces​here​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​.

In answers HTML comments can also play this role: `<!-- html comments -->`.

Since the SE markdown is largely ignored in comments, HTML comments and HTML character codes  in comments are displayed verbatim.  However, you can manually input special Unicode characters. The zero-width space is `U+200B`.  For example, on Windows you can input this by pressing and holding the `Alt` key, pressing the `+` key on the *keypad* then the hexadecimal Unicode value, and *then* releasing the `Alt` key: `Alt +200B` yields: »​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​« not much to see, unfortunately.

Comment: Too short:​​​​​

Comment: Nearly too long: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: &#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: So why do we need a minimum length when the workaround is trivial? I use it too, I confess...

Comment: @draks...: I would guess that the main reason for minimum comment lengths is to reduce the number of "thanks"-only comments (which most other SE sites are not as accepting of).  I wouldn't call these workarounds _trivial_, as they require _some_ knowledge of the system or the way computers work, and often it's easier to just include one or two extra words.

Comment: ok ${ }$ ${ }$ ${ }$

Comment: Too short$\qquad$`\qquad`.

Comment: @draks Even if Dollar signs and such were not counted in the character limit, one could just put "15char 15char 15char" at the end of their post, which accomplishes the same thing in a less subtle way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. (Is really the neatest way of saying "thanks" and doesn't require special characters...)